# Google Cloud Composer pulls stale image from Google Container Registry

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to run an Airflow task through Google Cloud Composer with the KubernetesPodOperator in an environment built from an image in a private Google Container Registry. The Container Registry and Cloud Composer instances are under the same project and everything worked fine until I updated the image the DAG refers too.

When I update the image in the Container Registry, Cloud Composer keeps using a stale image.

Concretely, in the code below

```
import datetime
import airflow
from airflow.contrib.operators import kubernetes_pod_operator


YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


# Create Airflow DAG the the pipeline
with airflow.DAG(
        'my_dag',
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        start_date=YESTERDAY) as dag:

    my_task = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id='my_task',
        name='my_task',
        cmds=['echo 0'],
        namespace='default',
        image=f'gcr.io/<my_private_repository>/<my_image>:latest')
```

if I update the image `gcr.io/<my_private_repository>/<my_image>:latest` in the Container Registry, Cloud Composer keeps using the stale image that is not present anymore in the Container Registry and throws an error.

Is this a bug?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was wondering if the current answer helped to resolved your issue. If not, I have two questions; 1) did you pushed the image with the [`latest`](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#push_the_tagged_image_to) tag? and 2) What is the error you received?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation for `KubernetesPodOperator`](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator/index.html#module-contents), the default value for `image_pull_policy` is `'IfNotPresent'`. You need to configure your Pod Spec to pull image image always.

Simplest way to do it is setting the `image_pull_policy` to `'Always'`.

Few more ways are mentioned in [K8s Container Images documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images).